# How to calculate user retention for a period of 1 month

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I currently have a table (MySQL) called `user_tracker` which stores:

1. User IP Address: `IpAddress`
2. A unique token per person (saved as a cookie): `CookieToken`
3. The URL the user checked: `Page`
4. The date the user checked that page: `CreatedOn`

What we want to do is see during the duration of 30 days how many people came to the site 1 time only, 2 times, 3 times, ... 30 times (meaning they came to the site every single day).

If a user views 5 pages in 1 day and never comes back that user is still considered as "1 time".

How can I get something like this?

**I would also appreciate if anyone knows the query to get this data on MySQL as well without the use of Tableau or others.**

Attached is a screenshot of previous month data gathered like this using SAS VA.

[image]

Comment: It would be _very_ helpful to others if you showed some sample table data.

Comment: Yes, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The Tableau feature that best addresses this type of problem is level of detail (LOD) calculations. Read about LOD calcs in the on-line help to get a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your createdOn is a valid date column you could count the number of rows in the date interval

use distinct createdOn if you need  the number of distinct days the user visit the site

```
  select 
      IpAddress
      , count(distinct createdOn)
  from my_table 
  where CreatedOn between  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
  group by IpAddress
```

use count(*) if you want to know how many times the user visit the site

Comment: Also, I doubt that createdon could be a future date

Comment: I have post this condition in answer .. hope that the OP let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a LOD calculated field, [Days Active in Month] to show the number of unique days of the month per person `{FIXED [CookieToken] : COUNTD(DAY([Created On])) }`
2. Place [Days Active in Month] on the row shelf
3. Place Month([Created On]) on the color shelf
4. Place COUNTD([CookieToken])on the columns shelf

Using COUNTD is convenient but costly for large data sets. If performance is not sufficient, then you might want to preprocess the data to pay that cost once up front.

The steps above assume all the data is from one year. If your data covers multiple years, you'll want to revise steps 1 and/or 3 accordingly